# Explicit homeomorphism from $I \times I$ to itself that maps $I\times \{0\} \cup \{0,1\} \times I$ to $I \times \{0\}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

My question is basic and I apologize in advance if it's too easy.

I've been reading some books on basic topology and I keep seeing the same thing: that there is an "obvious" homeomorphism: 
$$\varphi: I \times I  \to I \times I, $$
that takes $I \times \{0\} \cup \{0,1\} \times I$ to $I \times \{0\}$. But I cannot find an explicit formula.

The statement is quite general and I have found this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1746560) but the author says that it's obvious without explaining why. I'm sure it's obvious but I really want to see it.

Can anyone help ?

Thank you.

Comment: I can "see" it, but I have no idea how to write it down in coordinates.

Comment: Did you try to draw the sets? How do they look like?

Comment: @Paul K: Yes I did but I couldn't see it the homeomorphism doing this. Now thanks to Christoph's answer I believe I get it. I just want to make sure I'm getting it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an illustration of a piecewise linear homeomorphism with the desired property defined on 3 pieces: two triangles and a trapezoid.

[image: pl-homeomorphism]

On each piece you can obtain an explicit formula by putting any three vertices and their images into the general form of an affine linear map.

Comment: This is a great picture and a great answer. It saves me a lot of time. Just to make sure I understand very well: each triangle is the convex hull of its 3 vertices and the trapeze is the convex hull of its 4 vertices. Then to define a linear affine map, it suffices to choose the image of the respective vertices. Is that what you do ? Do you glue these linear maps along the blue edges also ?

Comment: Yep, that is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Gluing maps is a notion of descent (for example in Sheaf theory); but when we do so, we usually glue along open sub-objects (finite intersection of open covers for example). But here we glue along edges which are closed stuff. I wonder if this kind of gluing occur in other situations ? I'm new to Stack Exchange so I don't know if it's appropriate to ask a sub-question.